# Calling C# dll (wrapped in C++) in Java / A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, c#, c++, java-native-interface

I was following this link [how to wrap a c# library for use in java](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378826/How-to-wrap-a-Csharp-library-for-use-in-Java)
I think I didn't miss anything but I'm getting a crash.

Here's codes,

Java (project - package - class / jnitest - jni - Test1 )

```
  package jni;

  public class Test1 { 
    static {
      System.loadLibrary("Test");
      // System.load("/lib/Test.dll");
    }
    public native void displayHelloWorld();
    public static void main (String[] args) {
      // System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
      Test1 t = new Test1();
      t.displayHelloWorld();
    }
  }
```

JNI Header file generated from java (using eclipse)

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class jni_Test1 */

#ifndef _Included_jni_Test1
#define _Included_jni_Test1
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     jni_Test1
 * Method:    displayHelloWorld
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jni_Test1_displayHelloWorld
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

HelloWorld.h

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using "CSharpHelloWorld.netmodule"

using namespace System;

public ref class HelloWorldC
{
public:
    // Provide .NET interop and garbage collecting to the pointer.
    CSharpHelloWorld^ t;
    HelloWorldC() {
        t = gcnew CSharpHelloWorld();
        // Assign the reference a new instance of the object
    }

    // This inline function is called from the C++ Code
    void callCSharpHelloWorld() {
        t->displayHelloWorld();
    }
};
```

HelloWorld.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "jni_Test1.h"
#include "HelloWorld.h"


// This is the JNI call to the Managed C++ Class
// NOTE: When the java header was created, the package name was not include in the JNI call.
// This naming convention was corrected by adding the 
// "helloworld" name following the following syntax: 
// Java_<package name>_<class name>_<method name>
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jni_Test1_displayHelloWorld(JNIEnv *jn, jobject jobj) {

    // Instantiate the MC++ class.
    HelloWorldC^ t = gcnew HelloWorldC();

    // The actual call is made. 
    t->callCSharpHelloWorld();
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and when I tried to use * like reference link did, it gives me an error so I had to change in that way it doesn't thrown an error. (such as * -> ^, __gc -> gcnew and so on)

I succeeded to create dll file and put it in classpath and when I launched java file, it gives me error/log below

[error]

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=8020, tid=14744
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_31-b13) (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xc42d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\workspace\jnitest\hs_err_pid8020.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

[log]

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=8020, tid=14744
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_31-b13) (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xc42d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00ddc800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=14744, stack(0x00f10000,0x00f60000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xe0434352, ExceptionInformation=0x80070002 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x6e980000 

Registers:
EAX=0x00f5e3b0, EBX=0x00000005, ECX=0x00000005, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x00f5e3b0, EBP=0x00f5e400, ESI=0x00f5e46c, EDI=0x00000001
EIP=0x76a4c42d, EFLAGS=0x00000212

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00f5e3b0)
0x00f5e3b0:   e0434352 00000001 00000000 76a4c42d
0x00f5e3c0:   00000005 80070002 00000000 00000000
0x00f5e3d0:   00000000 6e980000 00f5f578 00000001
0x00f5e3e0:   00000000 006511c4 00004000 00446118
0x00f5e3f0:   00f5e404 758014ad 00412d28 00f5e3b8
0x00f5e400:   00f5e4a0 6ead8fdb e0434352 00000001
0x00f5e410:   00000005 00f5e46c 83662cfd 0043bd10
0x00f5e420:   15a62380 00f5e558 00412d28 00000001 

Instructions: (pc=0x76a4c42d)
0x76a4c40d:   02 50 ff 75 14 8d 45 c4 50 e8 57 ad 02 00 83 c4
0x76a4c41d:   0c eb 03 89 45 c0 8d 45 b0 50 ff 15 5c 11 a4 76
0x76a4c42d:   c9 c2 10 00 cc cc cc cc cc 8b ff 55 8b ec 56 8b
0x76a4c43d:   75 08 83 fe f4 72 18 83 fe f6 77 13 8d 45 08 50 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00f5e3b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00ddc800
EBX=0x00000005 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000005 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x00f5e3b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00ddc800
EBP=0x00f5e400 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00ddc800
ESI=0x00f5e46c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00ddc800
EDI=0x00000001 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00f10000,0x00f60000],  sp=0x00f5e3b0,  free space=312k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xc42d]
C  [clr.dll+0x158fdb]
C  [clr.dll+0x2cd607]
C  [clr.dll+0x2d57bc]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x38a6]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x2b72c]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x3066]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x325b]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x12fb]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x152b]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x1668]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x17b5]
C  [clrjit.dll+0x1802]
C  [clr.dll+0x388f9]
C  [clr.dll+0x38991]
C  [clr.dll+0x389d3]
C  [clr.dll+0x38405]
C  [clr.dll+0x3878c]
C  [clr.dll+0x1497b5]
C  [clr.dll+0x1b02b]
C  [clr.dll+0x2a0c]
C  0x00f0177f
C  0x0067b3f5
j  jni.Test1.displayHelloWorld()V+0
j  jni.Test1.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x1473e5]
V  [jvm.dll+0x20d57e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x14747e]
V  [jvm.dll+0xd0c27]
V  [jvm.dll+0xd91cf]
C  [javaw.exe+0x210a]
C  [javaw.exe+0xaba1]
C  [javaw.exe+0xac2b]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x1336a]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39882]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39855]
C  0x00000000

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  jni.Test1.displayHelloWorld()V+0
j  jni.Test1.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x14ee0000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13880, stack(0x15350000,0x153a0000)]
  0x14eb6c00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2028, stack(0x152d0000,0x15320000)]
  0x14eb5800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9236, stack(0x15230000,0x15280000)]
  0x14eb2800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14804, stack(0x150b0000,0x15100000)]
  0x14e80c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14892, stack(0x04910000,0x04960000)]
  0x14e7b400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13668, stack(0x002f0000,0x00340000)]
=>0x00ddc800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=14744, stack(0x00f10000,0x00f60000)]

Other Threads:
  0x14e78000 VMThread [stack: 0x01090000,0x010e0000] [id=13428]
  0x14ee1400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00920000,0x00970000] [id=13024]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 795K [0x04a00000, 0x04f50000, 0x09f50000)
  eden space 4416K,  18% used [0x04a00000, 0x04ac6ea8, 0x04e50000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x04e50000, 0x04e50000, 0x04ed0000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x04ed0000, 0x04ed0000, 0x04f50000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x09f50000, 0x0aa00000, 0x14a00000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x09f50000, 0x09f50000, 0x09f50200, 0x0aa00000)
 Metaspace       used 1695K, capacity 2242K, committed 2368K, reserved 4480K

Card table byte_map: [0x00f60000,0x00ff0000] byte_map_base: 0x00f3b000

Polling page: 0x000e0000

CodeCache: size=32768Kb used=677Kb max_used=677Kb free=32090Kb
 bounds [0x02830000, 0x028e0000, 0x04830000]
 total_blobs=156 nmethods=19 adapters=70
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.135 Thread 0x14eb6c00   15             java.lang.CharacterDataLatin1::getProperties (11 bytes)
Event: 0.135 Thread 0x14eb6c00 nmethod 15 0x028d7808 code [0x028d7900, 0x028d79a0]
Event: 0.135 Thread 0x14eb6c00   16             java.lang.String::toLowerCase (439 bytes)
Event: 0.136 Thread 0x14eb6c00 nmethod 16 0x028d7a48 code [0x028d7c50, 0x028d8440]
Event: 0.136 Thread 0x14eb6c00   17             java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::append (29 bytes)
Event: 0.137 Thread 0x14eb6c00 nmethod 17 0x028d8e88 code [0x028d8f90, 0x028d907c]
Event: 0.137 Thread 0x14eb6c00   18             java.lang.Character::toLowerCase (9 bytes)
Event: 0.137 Thread 0x14eb6c00 nmethod 18 0x028d9188 code [0x028d9290, 0x028d9338]
Event: 0.137 Thread 0x14eb6c00   19             java.lang.CharacterDataLatin1::toLowerCase (39 bytes)
Event: 0.137 Thread 0x14eb6c00 nmethod 19 0x028d93c8 code [0x028d94c0, 0x028d95a0]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (3 events):
Event: 0.091 Thread 0x00ddc800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x04a0b310) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u31\2394\hotspot\src\share\vVG½±¡4·?
Event: 0.091 Thread 0x00ddc800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x04a0b590) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u31\2394\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, l>x\b@vÁ?
Event: 0.136 Thread 0x00ddc800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x04abd8e8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-i586-cygwin\jdk8u31\2394\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1312]

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.139 loading class java/security/AllPermission
Event: 0.139 loading class java/security/AllPermission done
Event: 0.139 loading class java/security/UnresolvedPermission
Event: 0.139 loading class java/security/UnresolvedPermission done
Event: 0.139 loading class java/security/BasicPermissionCollection
Event: 0.139 loading class java/security/BasicPermissionCollection done
Event: 0.140 loading class sun/launcher/LauncherHelper$FXHelper
Event: 0.140 loading class sun/launcher/LauncherHelper$FXHelper done
Event: 0.140 loading class java/lang/Class$MethodArray
Event: 0.140 loading class java/lang/Class$MethodArray done


Dynamic libraries:
0x01130000 - 0x01160000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\javaw.exe
0x776a0000 - 0x77820000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x757f0000 - 0x75900000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x76a40000 - 0x76a87000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x771f0000 - 0x77291000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76790000 - 0x7683c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x76750000 - 0x76769000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x75990000 - 0x75a80000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x75010000 - 0x75070000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x75000000 - 0x7500c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x756f0000 - 0x757f0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x769b0000 - 0x76a40000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x76780000 - 0x7678a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x75540000 - 0x755dd000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x71420000 - 0x715be000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_41e855142bd5705d\COMCTL32.dll
0x76d70000 - 0x76dc7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x75690000 - 0x756f0000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x77120000 - 0x771ec000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x779e0000 - 0x77a9f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x530a0000 - 0x53444000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x74f40000 - 0x74f47000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x75250000 - 0x75285000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x75670000 - 0x75676000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x6ccf0000 - 0x6cd22000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x75500000 - 0x75505000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x74020000 - 0x7402c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\verify.dll
0x73ff0000 - 0x74011000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\java.dll
0x73fd0000 - 0x73fe3000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\zip.dll
0x75ad0000 - 0x7671b000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
0x76fc0000 - 0x7711c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x77670000 - 0x7767b000     C:\Windows\syswow64\profapi.dll
0x77840000 - 0x77850000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\Test.dll
0x6fb00000 - 0x6fb4a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
0x15590000 - 0x1574f000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR120D.dll
0x6f9f0000 - 0x6fa6e000     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
0x6e980000 - 0x6f01d000     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
0x6f750000 - 0x6f827000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
0x6d910000 - 0x6e97b000     C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\d1265d6159ea876f9d63ea4c1361b587\mscorlib.ni.dll
0x6f6d0000 - 0x6f74d000     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
0x76cd0000 - 0x76d5f000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x5dea0000 - 0x5df71000     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
0x6cf70000 - 0x6d90d000     C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\d18e2115a3270f89663fce831547f534\System.ni.dll
0x72040000 - 0x7212b000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: jni.Test1
java_class_path (initial): C:\workspace\jnitest\bin
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_31/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Wizvera\Delfino;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\platform-tools;C:\development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\tools;C:\Program Files\ANT\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\eclipse\mars;
USERNAME=MYUSER
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 8079004k(1694656k free), swap 16156168k(9124340k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.31-b07) for windows-x86 JRE (1.8.0_31-b13), built on Dec 17 2014 20:46:12 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Thu Aug 27 16:38:52 2015
elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

Comment: Your package doesn't match, "jnitest" (in the error) versus "jni" (in your code snippet).

Comment: My bad, I was launching different project. when I tried correct project, it shows other error. i updated the post. thanks.

Comment: Start stripping out inner details (`CSharpHelloWorld`, `HelloWorldC`) until you get something that doesn't crash.  That will identify which piece is causing the crash.